# rabbit-mq Queue not auto-deleted after consumers zero

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-websocket, spring-rabbit

[image]

I set option autoDelete as true for a queue, but sometime even if consumer is 0, the queue still exist How can I find the reason? and how to delete? thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20180307210613/https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html), the `Auto-delete` works if:

> queue that **has had at least one consumer** is deleted **when last consumer unsubscribes**

So the answer is it will get deleted as soon as a consumer subscribes then unsubscribes, so the `Consumer` count gets to `0`.

Comment: I already gave it, it's simple and plain. What else is there to explain? Connect to the queue then disconnect and it will get removed.

Comment: As @emix said, the queue must have had _at least one_ consumer. If you only declared the queues and then disconnected, they won't be deleted.